# How do I update overlapping indexes in a boost::multi_index_container?

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I'm using boost 1.48.0, and I don't have the option to upgrade.

I've built a multi_index_container with indexes that have overlapping criteria. How are indexes sharing the same indexing criteria effected, as in the following example? The last line of the example code alludes to what I am asking for.

```
struct street_address_key : composite_key<
    t_postal_address
    , const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::street_name>>
    , const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, long, &t_postal_address::house_number>>
    , const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::city>>
    , const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::state>>
    , const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, long, &t_postal_address::zip_code>>
> {};

multi_index<
    t_postal_address
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<street_address_key>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::name>>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::street_name>>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, long, &t_postal_address::house_number>>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::city>>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::state>>
        , ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, long, &t_postal_address::zip_code>>
    >
> t_address_book;

...

t_address_book::nth_element<0>::type::iterator address_iter = book.find(some_address_tuple);

book.modify(address_iter, modify_city_method);

auto city_range = book.get<4>().equal_range( \*???*\ );
```

The city index shares the same criteria as the street_address_key. Modifying via the street_address_key, as I understand it, would ensure the index is appropriately updated. But what is the state of the "city" index? Was it updated to reflect the change in city name? Or is it in a broken state? Could I still locate the same address index with the old city? Do I have to update this index separately? Could I call a no-op Modifier to update the index?

```
// Presume I have the city element from the index.
// Is this supposed to update the city index after it was modified above?

book.get<4>().modify(city_iter, [](t_postal_address &) {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there should be no problem:

The documentation mentions:

> Effects: Calls mod(e) where e is the element pointed to by position and rearranges `*position` into all the indices of the multi_index_container. Rearrangement is successful if
>
> - the index is non-unique OR no other element exists with equivalent key,
> - AND rearrangement is allowed by all other indices of the multi_index_container.
>     If the rearrangement fails, the element is erased.

This implies all indexes are updated. Note that all indexes can in principle reject the edit. You may want to use a rollback to protect against loss of data.

Comment: Maybe it's been a long day, but I have seen that, and for the life of me, I couldn't figure that out. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewReddington I have the same feeling reading boost docs. That's a GoodThing(TM) though because it reminds me to **test**. It's too easy to be lulled into a false sense of security with "nice API". Multi Index containers _are complicated_. The complexity is intrinsic and inevitable. The complexity is of a semantic nature. Be sure you know what your operations do by testing (in this case, at least 4 updates arranged "in a square" to exercise various cases with non-coherent, overlapping indices)

Comment: That's precisely what I'm doing. We're using a multi_index_container in our production software and I suspect it's a performance bottleneck. I'm writing a test program to explore alternative container layouts and alternative data structures overall (please let SQLite3 be fast enough, please let SQLite3 be fast enough, please let SQLite3 be fast enough...).

Comment: SQLite3 is fast, depending on how you use it. Performance (or whatever scaling) is hard and requires careful planning and tuning. That said, I treat multi-index as a convenience only. I prefer to decide when my indices are generated/updated in performance critical scenarios.

Comment: Regarding Boost.MultiIndex's performance, of course you should profile and test against alternatives, but in general the lib is *very* fast. I guess you haven't set safe or invariant checking modes, right? http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/debug.html

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz of course not. The library is fast /for what it does/. But oftentimes we don't need indexes always-up-to-date. I found that especially bulk-inserting can be a bottle-neck. And there's not a lot of use for a multi-index container without considerable data (for small collections, vector + linear search trumps everything). So there's that. So, for me, BMI is still for cases where I don't sweat the performance under update/insertion. Which is 90% of the time :)

Answer (score 1):

As @sehe comments, indices are all updated so you're safe. Additional observation: your index #2

```
ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<const_mem_fun<t_postal_address, string, &t_postal_address::street_name>>
```

is actually redundant with index #0 (the one based on a composite key): you can pass just a string (representing a street name) to index #0 and it'll behave exactly as index #2. This saves you some space and execution time. The magic behind it lies in the fact that when using composite keys you're allowed to pass *partial information*, down to just the first element of the composite key.

Comment: This is good. I don't think anyone here knows this; I certainly didn't. Hopefully I can eliminate *TWO* indexes from our production code based on this fact. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at

http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys

particularly the paragraph starting with "As a notational convenience..."