# Multi index hash table implementation

Tags: python, c++, boost, data-structures

I have a table of records that needs to be looked up fast, as such decided to go for hash table lookup.

Now, the problem that came out eventually is that I had to lookup a record(s) based on multiple keys.

For e.g., all 4 keys below should point to same record.

```
key1 -> a,b,c,d,e
key2 -> a,b,d
key3 -> a,b,e
key4 -> c
```

Problem #1
This pattern then showed similarity to database lookups, where multiple keys are specified. So, would B-tree data structure be optimal to use than a multiple hash table design ?

Problem #2
Whether a special trie was better suited to the problem. The default implementation would require all keys a+b+c+d+e as lookup key. If I had to lookup a+b+d, then from this master key would have to skip c & e while looking up. But then would this idea work or is already out there ?

Problem #3
Another idea was whether I insert things into my table, parallely I build up another lookup table with index to each record. That way I could multiple masks for each key and scan this lookup table for the records that match. Something similar to CAM tables I guess. But then performance would go down if I have to scan entire table. Would it be possible to mix hash table + indexing logic together giving speed and optimal memory usage ?

So far have tried using boost multi index, uthash, trie, etc to try and achieve a design that suits all 4 problems but not successful so far. I liked boost multi index but it has it's own share of problems which prohibits me to use.

Though I use C language for programming and testing out the designs, I'm quite ok with any other language like java,php,python.

Any other ideas for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Pseudo code of the solution I would like to achieve:

```
/* Keys */
struct key1_s {
int src;
int dst;
char name[10];
int t1;
int t2;
};

struct key2_s {
int src;
int dst;
char name[10];
};

struct key3_s {
int src;
int dst;
int t1;
};


struct key4_s {
int src;
int dst;
int t2;
};


/* Record */
struct record_s {
int src;
int dst;
char name[10];
int t1;
int t2;
int age;
int sex;
int mobile;
}

struct record_s record[2] = {
{1, 2, "jack", 5, 6, 50, 1, 1234567890},
{3, 4, "john", 7, 8, 60, 2, 1122334455}
};
table.insert(record[0]);
table.insert(record[1]);

/* search using key1 */
struct key1_s key1;
key1.src = 1;
key1.dst = 2;
strncpy(key1.name, "jack", 10);
key1.t1 = 5;
key1.t2 = 6;
table.find(key1); // should return pointer to record[0]

/* search using key2 */
struct key2_s key2;
key2.src = 1;
key2.dst = 2;
strncpy(key1.name, "jack", 10);
table.find(key2); // should return pointer to record[0]

/* search using key3 */
struct key3_s key3;
key3.src = 1;
key3.dst = 2;
key3.t1  = 5;
table.find(key3); // should return pointer to record[0]
```

If the find() returns a successful pointer, then I would like to update the fields of record like age, sex, mobile.

Comment: sry for the confusion in notation, to clarify what I meant, adding some pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

Boost Multi Index can help here.

The `composite_keys.cpp` example contains a compelling example. You just need to globally replace `ordered` with `hashed` to get what you are dealing with (also, in your case there would be more overlap in the key configurations).

With respect to the performance questions, I do not think there's a clear-cut answer; it (always) depends on the usage patterns. You will need to profile and balance the amount of effort to be spent in optimizing.

I personally consider Boost Multi Index the sweet spot when focus is on convenience and quick results. Note that this, by no means, means that BMI is not optimized (I believe it is highly optimized); however it will /always/ depend on usage patterns. (Consider an application that bulk inserts large amounts of data initially, then just reads; such an application could benefit from building the the indices once, explicitly, instead of automatically updating all indices on each insertion).

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4267ac0583ec51fb)**

```
using namespace boost::multi_index;

/* A file record maintains some info on name and size as well
 * as a pointer to the directory it belongs (null meaning the root
 * directory.)
 */

struct file_entry
{
  file_entry(
    std::string name_,unsigned size_,bool is_dir_,const file_entry* dir_):
    name(name_),size(size_),is_dir(is_dir_),dir(dir_)
  {}

  std::string       name;
  unsigned          size;
  bool              is_dir;
  const file_entry* dir;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const file_entry& f)
  {
      os << f.name << "\t" << f.size;
      if (f.is_dir)os << "\t <dir>";
      return os;
  }
};

/* A file system is just a multi_index_container of entries with indices on
 * file and size (per directory). 
 */
struct dir_and_name_key:composite_key<
  file_entry,
  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(file_entry,const file_entry*,dir),
  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(file_entry,std::string,name)
>{};

struct dir_and_size_key:composite_key<
  file_entry,
  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(file_entry,const file_entry* const,dir),
  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(file_entry,unsigned,size)
>{};

typedef multi_index_container<
  file_entry,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<dir_and_name_key>,
    hashed_non_unique<dir_and_size_key>
  >
> file_system;

/* typedef's of the two indices of file_system */
typedef nth_index<file_system,0>::type file_system_by_name;
typedef nth_index<file_system,1>::type file_system_by_size;

/* We build a rudimentary file system simulation out of some global
 * info and a map of commands provided to the user.
 */

static file_system fs;                 /* the one and only file system */
static file_system_by_name& fs_by_name=fs;         /* name index to fs */
static file_system_by_size& fs_by_size=get<1>(fs); /* size index to fs */
static const file_entry* current_dir=0;            /* root directory   */
```

Comment: I've used BMI for this problem but found some issues with the following use cases:

Comment: I've used BMI for this problem but I came across few issues while trying to address my problem. The usage pattern I have is initially there will be bulk inserts, after that at high rates there will be updates/deletes. This is where I got hit I feel. Whenever I had to update a record in the table, calling table.replace(key, newrecord) would actually delete the old record and insert a new record. I found this to be quite expensive operation. Instead was hoping that I could just go ahead and update the record if I can get a pointer to it.

Comment: You cannot avoid updating indices unless you don't update the key fields. It's fine to modify through a reference unless you modify key fields

Comment: Use `modify` rather than `replace`: this is as fast as it gets, no deletion/insertion takes place.

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz I suppose if you know you're not updating keyfields, it would be faster to operate directly on the objects? Also, doesn't [your observation made ***here***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23079553/85371) play into the particular scenario given by the OP? I admit I had forgotten until I saw your name :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to update the key fields sometimes. Would have to selectively use modify() for non-key fields then. Will try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Is there any other data structure that can achieve the same result as BMI ?

Comment: @Athif on the conrary. You would want to selectively use `modify(...)` for the key fields! (And, if you /only/ update a the key, `modify_key(...)` could be convenient with e.g. Phoenix expressions).

Comment: @Athif Yes, You can write data structures that can achieve the same result as BMI. And it would be foolish to write it, obviously. Why write the same again? However, what you mean is: "can I get a different trade off"? Answer: Yes. No ready made solution exists, but you can make one if you know what you are trying to achieve. You could look at Boost Intrusive to do some of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Athif However, the real trick is designing an API that protects your invariants (and the only way to really change performance  characteristics would be to be able to temporarily suspend those; I'd say, be absolutely convinced you need this last drop of performance because it always comes at a (hefty, I intuitively guess here) complexity price.) This kind of API design takes a lot of experience. Boost Multi Index directly benefits from years of use, testing and peer review. Just my $0.02

Comment: Yes, totally with you on not-reinventing the wheel like BMI. For now I guess its better to selectively using modify/replace for non-key/key fields respectively. However, I was hoping to find some alternate clever approach/datastructure to tackle this problem. Something similar to BMI but allowing key fields to be updated as well, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Athif, you got it wrong, `modify` is suitable for key fields. For non-key fields you can `const_cast` the element to non-const and change the field directly.